# Is there a better regex to truncate semantic version to major version?

Tags: regex, maven, semantic-versioning

Tried a few regex expressions but uncertain about correctness. As they say now I have two problems so here comes my question.

Problem to solve is using a major version in a Dockerfile. Tools in use - Maven, a few maven plugins (including `build-helper-maven-plugin`), Docker.

Essentially attempting to extract major version from a string using regex and unsure if it's entirely correct. Ideally I can assume a semantic version string however there are some insanities out there.

Any string regex which should work for all cases even if someone uses a major version that's not a numeric digit

```
\.(.*)$
```

Semantic version regex - ensures numeric digits and format

```
\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$
```

Regex above was modified from [ihateregex semver](https://ihateregex.io/expr/semver/).

Examples for cli users

```bash
➜ pcregrep -C 10 -M --color '\.(.*)$' version-examples.txt
➜ pcregrep -C 10 -M --color '\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$' version-examples.txt

version-examples.txt below
1
a.0.1
0.0.4
1.2.3
1.2
10.20.30
01.1.1
1.1.2-prerelease+meta
1.1.2+meta
9.8.7-whatever+meta+meta
1.0.0-alpha
1.0.0-alpha.beta
1.0.0-alpha.1
1.0.0-alpha.0valid
1.0.0-rc.1+build.1
1.2.3-beta
10.2.3-DEV-SNAPSHOT
1.2.3.DEV
1.2.3-0123
1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-123
1.0.0
2.0.0+build.1848
2.0.1-alpha.1227
1.0.0-alpha+beta
1.0.0-alpha_beta
1.2.3----RC-SNAPSHOT.12.9.1--.12+788
1.2.3----R-S.12.9.1--.12+meta
1.2-SNAPSHOT
1.2.31.2.3----RC-SNAPSHOT.12.09.1--..12+788
```

Could you think of a better solution to the above expressions?

Comment: I think that the major version is just the stuff between the beginning of the version string and the first dot. That is easy to parse with regex.

Comment: I would recommend to take a look into: https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion @khmarbaise. I have already looked into the plugin however it does not achieve my end goal. Plugin is used to parse maven artifact version and I'm trying to solve a more generic problem here. Also I've already seen an example of [maven-release-plugin-example](https://github.com/mortenberg80/maven-release-example) which demonstrates how to use the plugin.

Comment: There's a better list of oracles to test against here: https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/833#issuecomment-1186845563